# using a for loop in javascript write a code that prompts the user to enter any amount of numbers the print the largest and smallest of those numbers

Tags: javascript

new to JS, here's the problem, code to ask user to enter any amount of numbers -1 to end, find and display the largest and smallest; it's working except that it displays the smallest as the largest but the largest displays 
fine??

```
    var numInputs = parseInt(prompt("Please enter numbers seperated by
      a space end with -1"))
    var largestNum =0;
    var smallestNum = 9999;


if (numInputs >0)
{
  for (i=1; i<=numInputs; i++)
  {

if (numInputs > largestNum)
{
   largestNum = numInputs;
}
  }
}
alert("The largest number entered was " + largestNum);

if (numInputs >0)
{
  for (i=1; i<=numInputs; i++)
  {

    if (numInputs < smallestNum)
    {
   smallestNum = numInputs;
    }
  }
}

alert("The smallest number entered was " + smallestNum);
```

Comment: *"it's working except"* - I really don't think it is working at all. `parseInt()` doesn't work the way you seem to think it does: if you give it a string of space-separated numbers it will return the first number. Even if it did return an array of all the numbers, or a count of all the numbers, your loop wouldn't make sense because you're comparing `numInputs` to your `largestNum` variable; you never use `i` within the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that `numInputs` only parses the first number you put. so if you put the string "1 2 3 4 5 -1", `numInputs` gets the value 1.

Here is a code snippet that will fix your problem:

```
var largestNum, smallestNum;
var numInput = parseInt(prompt("Please enter the next number (-1 to exit)"));
if (numInput != -1) {
    largestNum = numInput;
    smallestNum = numInput;
}

while (numInput != -1) {
    if (numInput > largestNum) {
        largestNum = numInput;
    } else if (numInput < smallestNum) {
        smallestNum = numInput;
    }
    numInput = parseInt(prompt("Please enter the next number (-1 to exit)"));
}

alert("Smallest number is " + smallestNum + ", largest number is " + largestNum);
```

as you can see, I update the smallest and largest numbers as I get them, in real-time, and not after I get all the input.
Also, I set the first number as both the smallest and largest one, for simplicity (not working with fixed values as 0 and 9999, which may be wrong).
Lastly, I did a prompt separately for each number, so you can't input them all together. To do that, you're gonna have to `split` the string and store in an array, and iterate over the array elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = [],
    value;

value = parseInt(prompt("Please enter numbers seperated by a space end with - 1 "));
while (value !== -1) {
    a.push(value);
    value = parseInt(prompt("Please enter numbers seperated by a space end with - 1 "));
}

a.sort();
console.log(a);

alert("The largest number entered was " + a[a.length-1]);
alert("The smallest number entered was " + a[0]);
```

**Edit:**
If you want to sort numbers that are larger than 9, use :

```
a.sort(function(a,b){ return a - b });
```

Comment: well you need to put only one number because of parseInt()

Comment: Yes, that was my point. I'll delete my previous comment now that you've fixed it with an edit.

Answer (score 0):

How about refactoring your code a bit here. We remove the `parseInt` since it dosent work and the take the entered numbers `split` them by a space making an array out of it `sorting the array` then just `poping` and `shifting` numbers from it which just removes the last and first number respectively.

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/mgLnxqyu/1/).

Code:

```
var numbers = prompt("please enter a range of numbers separated by a space:");

var arrayOfNumbers = numbers.split(" ").sort();

alert("Lowest entered number:" + arrayOfNumbers.pop() + "\n highest entered number: " + arrayOfNumbers.shift());
```

Comment: This is nice and neat, but it won't quite work given that `.sort()` doesn't (by default) do a numeric sort.

Comment: @nnnnnn Just something that came to mind since i've noticed  that it's a string by default. maybe just parsing the output value  as a int would be what he's looking for if it's needed.

Comment: You just need to pass a comparison function to `.sort()` and it'll work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/mgLnxqyu/3/ - note also you need to sort it in descending order or reverse your use of `.pop()` and `.shift()` (since `.pop()` takes from the *end* of the array).

Answer (score 0):

You code doesn't make too much sense.

**numInputs** will be a string(numbers separated by space), you need to parse it intro an Array, like:

```
numInputs = prompt("Please enter numbers...")).split(" ");
```

Then you should loop through Array and check for max and minimum numbers, like :

```
var smallestNum = numInputs[0];
var largestNum = numInputs[0];

for(var i=0; i<numInputs.length; i++) {
    if (smallestNum > numInputs[i]) {
        smallestNum = numInputs[i];
    } else if (largestNum < numInputs[i]) {
        largestNum = numInputs[i];
    }
}
```